# What is the native keyword in Java for?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native, keyword

While playing [this puzzle](http://www.sporcle.com/games/robv/java_keywords) (It's a Java keyword trivia game), I came across the `native` keyword.

What is the native keyword in Java used for?

Comment: See also [What is native implementation in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/557574/122607), [Usage of native in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2902618/122607) and [What does the native keyword do ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3598315/122607).

Answer (score 367, accepted):

The `native` keyword is applied to a method to indicate that the method is implemented in native code using JNI (Java Native Interface).

Comment: The actual implementation doesn’t have to use JNI. Certain JRE methods are handled intrinsically by the JVM. In fact, it’s not even mandatory that the implementation is actually *native* code. It’s just [“implemented in a language other than the Java programming language”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6-200-A.1).

Comment: How can you go about implementing a method in native code using JNI? How to you tell the JVM to use this code? How do you write your java code to include this code?

Answer (score 535):

**Minimal runnable example**

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public native int square(int i);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("Main");
        System.out.println(new Main().square(2));
    }
}
```

Main.c

```c
#include <jni.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Main_square(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint i) {
  return i * i;
}
```

Compile and run:

```bash
sudo apt-get install build-essential openjdk-7-jdk
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64'
javac Main.java
javah -jni Main
gcc -shared -fpic -o libMain.so -I${JAVA_HOME}/include \
  -I${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux Main.c
java -Djava.library.path=. Main
```

Output:

```
4
```

Tested on Ubuntu 14.04 AMD64. Also worked with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45.

[Example on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/java-cheat/tree/77437774e632ba6ecb483f6e69726431a23b5808/jni) for you to play with.

Underscores in Java package / file names must be escaped with `_1` in the C function name as mentioned at: [Invoking JNI functions in Android package name containing underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069209/invoking-jni-functions-in-android-package-name-containing-underscore/35015592#35015592)

**Interpretation**

`native` allows you to:

- call a compiled dynamically loaded library (here written in C) with arbitrary assembly code from Java
- and get results back into Java

This could be used to:

- write faster code on a critical section with better CPU assembly instructions (not CPU portable)
- make direct system calls (not OS portable)

with the tradeoff of lower portability.

It is also possible for you to call Java from C, but you must first create a JVM in C: [How to call Java functions from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c)

Analogous native extension APIs are also present in many other "VM languages" for the same reasons, e.g. [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/index.html), [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), [Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/extension_rdoc.html).

**Android NDK**

The concept is exact the same in this context, except that you have to use Android boilerplate to set it up.

The official NDK repository contains "canonical" examples such as the hello-jni app:

- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/4df5a2705e471a0818c6b2dbc26b8e315d89d307/hello-jni/app/src/main/java/com/example/hellojni/HelloJni.java#L39
- https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/4df5a2705e471a0818c6b2dbc26b8e315d89d307/hello-jni/app/src/main/cpp/hello-jni.c#L27

In you `unzip` an `.apk` with NDK on Android O, you can see the pre-compiled `.so` that corresponds to the native code under `lib/arm64-v8a/libnative-lib.so`.

TODO confirm: furthermore, `file /data/app/com.android.appname-*/oat/arm64/base.odex`, says it is a shared library, which I think is the AOT precompiled .dex corresponding to the Java files in ART, see also: [What are ODEX files in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593527/what-are-odex-files-in-android) So maybe the Java is actually also run via a `native` interface?

**Example in the OpenJDK 8**

Let's find find where `Object#clone` is defined in jdk8u60-b27.

We will conclude that it is implemented with a `native` call.

First we find:

```bash
find . -name Object.java
```

which leads us to [jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l212](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/afbc08ea922b/src/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#l212):

```
protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

Now comes the hard part, finding where clone is amidst all the indirection. The query that helped me was:

```bash
find . -iname object.c
```

which would find either C or C++ files that might implement Object's native methods. It leads us to [jdk/share/native/java/lang/Object.c#l47](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/afbc08ea922b/src/share/native/java/lang/Object.c#l47):

```c
static JNINativeMethod methods[] = {
    ...
    {"clone",       "()Ljava/lang/Object;",   (void *)&JVM_Clone},
};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_Object_registerNatives(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls)
{
    (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, cls,
                            methods, sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0]));
}
```

which leads us to the `JVM_Clone` symbol:

```bash
grep -R JVM_Clone
```

which leads us to [hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l580](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/hotspot/file/10ad4b9d79f9/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#l580):

```cpp
JVM_ENTRY(jobject, JVM_Clone(JNIEnv* env, jobject handle))
    JVMWrapper("JVM_Clone");
```

After expanding a bunch of macros, we come to the conclusion that this is the definition point.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just a footnote : for a `static` `native` Java method, the second parameter of the C++ function is of type `jclass` and not `jobject`.

Comment: @SR_ thanks for the info. Was there a mistake on my answer, or is it just some extra info?

Comment: @Ciro it's some extra info for those who begin with your example (an answer with about 300 on SO may serve as reference). I've had a function with an incorrect signature called with a mess on the stack, with no error reported (at any of compile, link or run times). Thus I find it important to mention to be careful on this step.

Comment: @HuazheYin Sun Zi once said: "the superior non-accepted answer gets more votes than the superior accepted answer, because of upvoters who seek justice". True story. Some related points: https://cirosantilli.com/#the-machiavellian-stack-overflow-contributor

Answer (score 435):

It marks a method, that it will be implemented in other languages, not in Java. It works together with JNI (Java Native Interface).

Native methods were used in the past to write performance critical sections but with Java getting faster this is now less common. Native methods are currently needed when

- You need to call a library from Java that is written in other language.
- You need to access system or hardware resources that are only reachable from the other language (typically C). Actually, many system functions that interact with real computer (disk and network IO, for instance) can only do this because they call native code.

See Also
[Java Native Interface Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

Comment: This is my understanding I write  System.currentTimeMillis() (which is native) in java file and then this to work, JNI will call libraries or some functions written in C or C++ or assembly language and then return some value back to my java code. ex: here currentTimeMillis method invokes a native code with the help of JNI and that native code talks to system resource ex: a timer sitting on motherboard and thus getting return value (system time). correct me, please?

Comment: @MKod methods like `currentTimeMillis` are part of the JDK and they are annotated with `native` because the implementation is in the JDK source code itself. It's very unlikely that the implementation uses assembly language; it probably calls an API method of the operating system which the JVM is running on top of. For example on Windows it may call a DLL method `GetSystemTime` in kernel32.dll. On another OS it will have a different implementation. However when you use `native` for a method you are writing (as opposed to a JDK method) you have to provide the implementation using JNI.

Comment: This statement is the important one for Native keyword... ' You need to access system or hardware resources that are only reachable from the other language (typically C) ' .

Comment: @Kidburla May I ask what you mean by the "implementation is in the JDK source code itself"? `currentTimeMillis` is marked as native in `java.lang.System` so it uses JNI, isn't that right?

Comment: @flow2k yes, what you have said is probably true, I'm not sure why I said that in my comment (more than 2 years ago)

Comment: @flow2k not every `native` method uses JNI. In case of JRE methods, known to the JVM, there can be other mechanisms. E.g. `Object.getClass()` will not use JNI. But for native application methods that ought to run on different compatible JVMs, JNI is the standard interface.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the note. In this case, I suppose `currentTimeMillis` is an application method so would fall under JNI. About the "JRE methods" you mention - what are some good examples? I don't think I've ever called one myself - presumably they're low-level.

Comment: @flow2k There was an example already given: `Object::getClass`.

Answer (score 61):

Straight from [the *Java Language Specification*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.4):

> A method that is `native` is implemented in platform-dependent code, typically written in another programming language such as C, C++, FORTRAN,or assembly language. The body of a `native` method is given as a semicolon only, indicating that the implementation is omitted, instead of a block.

Answer (score 18):

As SLaks answered, the `native` keyword is for calling native code.

It also used by [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) for implementing javascript methods.

Answer (score 13):

functions that implement native code are declared native.

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call, and to be called by, native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Answer (score 9):

NATIVE is Non access modifier.it can be applied only to METHOD.
It indicates the PLATFORM-DEPENDENT implementation of method or code.

Answer (score 7):

native is a keyword in java , which is used to make unimplemented structure(method) like as abstract but it would be a platform dependent such as native code and execute from native stack not java stack.

Answer (score 7):

Java `native` method provides a mechanism for Java code to call OS native code, either due to functional or performance reasons.

Example:

- [java.lang.Rutime](https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/current/classfile?classfilelocation=java.lang.runtime) ([source code on github](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Runtime.java)) contains the following native method definition

```
606  public native int availableProcessors();
617  public native long freeMemory();
630  public native long totalMemory();
641  public native long maxMemory();
664  public native void gc();
```

In the corresponding `Runtime.class` file in OpenJDK, located in `JAVA_HOME/jmods/java.base.jmod/classes/java/lang/Runtime.class`, contains these methods and tagged them with `ACC_NATIVE` (`0x0100`), and these methods do not contain the [Code attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3), which means these method do not have any actual coding logic in the `Runtime.class` file:

- Method 13 `availableProcessors`: tagged as native and no Code attribute
- Method 14 `freeMemory`: tagged as native and no Code attribute
- Method 15 `totalMemory`: tagged as native and no Code attribute
- Method 16 `maxMemory`: tagged as native and no Code attribute
- Method 17 `gc`: tagged as native and no Code attribute

[image]

The in fact coding logic is in the corresponding [Runtime.c](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Runtime.c) file:

```
42  #include "java_lang_Runtime.h"
43
44  JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
45  Java_java_lang_Runtime_freeMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
46  {
47      return JVM_FreeMemory();
48  }
49
50  JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
51  Java_java_lang_Runtime_totalMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
52  {
53      return JVM_TotalMemory();
54  }
55
56  JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL
57  Java_java_lang_Runtime_maxMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
58  {
59      return JVM_MaxMemory();
60  }
61
62  JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
63  Java_java_lang_Runtime_gc(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
64  {
65      JVM_GC();
66  }
67  
68  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
69  Java_java_lang_Runtime_availableProcessors(JNIEnv *env, jobject this)
70  {
71      return JVM_ActiveProcessorCount();
72  }
```

And these `C` coding is compiled into the `libjava.so` (Linux) or `libjava.dll` (Windows) file, located at `JAVA_HOME/jmods/java.base.jmod/lib/libjava.so`:

[image]

[image]

Reference

- [Java Native Methods Essentials](https://binarydoc.blogspot.com/2020/04/java-native-methods-essentials-from.html)

Answer (score 6):

- `native` is a keyword in Java, it indicates platform dependent.
- `native` methods act as an interface between Java (JNI) and other programming languages.