# Is a Dalvik virtual machine instance created for each application?

Tags: android, dalvik

Is a Dalvik virtual machine instance created for each application, or all Android applications share the same Dalvik virtual machine instance?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the developer docs:

> Every Android application runs in its own process, with its own
> instance of the Dalvik virtual machine. Dalvik has been written so
> that a device can run multiple VMs efficiently.
>
> The Dalvik VM executes files in the Dalvik Executable (`.dex`) format
> which is optimised for minimal memory footprint.
>
> The VM is register-based, and runs classes compiled by a Java language
> compiler that have been transformed into the `.dex` format by the
> included `dx` tool.

Also have a look at [What is... The Dalvik Virtual Machine](http://www.electronicsweekly.com/blogs/eyes-on-android/what-is/the-dalvik-virtual-machine-2011-10/) for detailed description about DVM.

Comment: Yes, in the general case, though one app can be configured to use multiple processes, and multiple apps from the same publisher configured to run under the same userid can share a process.

Answer (score 38):

1. The Dalvik virtual machine is built specifically for Android. It was built to address the *battery life* and *processing power* problems, and it is *free*.
2. We are using Dalvik VM instead of Java Virtual Machine (JVM) because the Java compiler, the Java tools are free, but the JVM is not free, so the Android developers from Google have made their own virtual machine, and made it as free.
3. A virtual machine is necessary because the virtual machine helps in debugging, as a virtual computer so that my applications can run different devices the same way

#### Pictorial Representation

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 32):

A `.java` file is given to the java compiler (`javac`) to generate the `.class` file.

All `.class` files are given to `dx` tool to generate a single `dex` file.

The `dex` file is given to the Dalvik VM to generate the final machine code.

The final machine code is given to the CPU to execute.

Comment: How does this answer the original question?

Answer (score 14):

All apk's basic source code is in java language . When you build this project all .java files get converted to .class now the dx tool of adk converts all .class files to classes.dex file .And this classes.dex file is executed on dalvik virtual machine.

For more info on dalvik virtual machine: http://www.slideshare.net/jserv/understanding-the-dalvik-virtual-machine

Dalvik virtual machine is intended to run multiple VMs at a time .
So every app runs in its own process, with its own instance of the Dalvik virtual machine as said by @sahilMahajanMj .

And this classes.dex file is further optimized to odex file and saved in /dalvik/dalvik-cache
To know more about odex [click this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593527/what-are-odex-files-in-android) .

If you want to know why DVM for android why not JVM [click this](http://imsciences.edu.pk/serg/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/Analysis-of-Dalvik-VM.pdf)

Comment: @NoBugs:jus a min im checkin

Comment: Nope, it may be from sites you logged in to?

Comment: When you build this project all .java files get converted to .class **WHO IS DOING THIS**

Comment: @bumba The Java Compiler does this

Answer (score 2):

**Dalvik** is a virtual machine where every android application runs. Through Dalvik, device is able to run multiple virtual machines through better memory management as Dalvik VMs are register based and hence memory efficient

Every android app runs in its own process, with its own instance of Dalvik VM. 
First, Java files are connverted to .class file by java compiler
.class files are given to "dx" tool which converts it to .dex format
.dex file is given to DVM to produce machine code
Machine code is executed by CPU

.apk file contains .dex file in zip format which can be run on Dalvik VMs

Why Dalvik ?
    1. DVM are built for battery life, processing power and its free
    2. We're using DVM instead of JVM as JVM is not free
Dalvik VMs gives consistency across all the mobile devices i.e. one application will run across different devices in the same way