# How and what converts the Java bytecode to Android dex files?

Tags: android, dalvik

How and what exactly converts the java byte-code to dex file in Android ?

I know that the only part Android people have done to save them from licensing issues, making the system fast for execution, low memory need and other more features as it is register based VM.

But what name I can tell to the part it doing so?

Comment: If you want to know more about how to convert classes.jar to dex file, you need get more information on the dex file format(https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html). After knowing the detail of the dex file format, you will know how dx works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go through bellow url and read all details 
[Detail URL](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/index.html)

The general process for a typical build is outlined below:

1. The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) takes your application resource files, such as the AndroidManifest.xml file and the XML files for your Activities, and compiles them. An R.java is also produced so you can reference your resources from your Java code.
2. The aidl tool converts any .aidl interfaces that you have into Java interfaces.
3. All of your Java code, including the R.java and .aidl files, are
   compiled by the Java compiler and .class files are output.
4. The dex tool converts the .class files to Dalvik byte code. Any 3rd party libraries and .class files that you have included in your project are also converted into .dex files so that they can be packaged into the final .apk file.
5. All non-compiled resources (such as images), compiled resources, and
   the .dex files are sent to the apkbuilder tool to be packaged into
   an .apk file.
6. Once the .apk is built, it must be signed with either a debug or release key before it
   can be installed to a device.
7. Finally, if the application is being signed in release mode, you
   must align the .apk with the zipalign tool. Aligning the final .apk
   decreases memory usage when the application is running on a device.

[image]

Comment: Do you have more information on "dex tool converts"? My question points to same.

Comment: http://davidehringer.com/software/android/The_Dalvik_Virtual_Machine.pdf check this link and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577733/how-an-android-application-is-executed-on-dalvik-virtual-machine