# In the DVM architecture where is the machine code?

Tags: java, android, jvm, jit, dvm

Have been searching stackoverflow for an answer but to no avail.
From a link in this site
[How an Android application is executed on Dalvik Virtual Machine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577733/how-an-android-application-is-executed-on-dalvik-virtual-machine)
There is a diagram of the code compiling flow

[image]

Simple question is where is the machine code(or the final code or the native instructions)?

Is the dalvik byte code the machine code(the final converted or compiled code)?

Or there is another compilation step?

Also where is the traced JIT compilation present in among the block?Is it in DEX compiler or in DVM?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can find the compiler-part of Dalvik [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/ics-mr1-release/vm/compiler/).

Comment: @Michael Many thanks for your info.

Answer (score 0):

Ok think have found an answer.

1.Compilation flow

.java file -- given to -- java compiler -- to generate -- .class file.

all .class files -- given to -- dx tool -- to generate single -- dex file

dex file -- given to -- dvm -- to generate -- final machine code.

final machine code -- given to -- CPU -- to execute.

2.A JIT compiler is a feature of JVM that compiles chunks of JVM instructions to native machine code.

If there is any misintepretation please notify in comments.Will fix the answer.

Thanks for your time.