# How to programmatically detect odex file of my app?

Tags: android

How to detect programmatically if my android app has an odex file?
I want to know the java code to detect if my android app has an odex file or not?

I am developer android app. I want to know what is java code should I embed to my android app to detect if its has been odexed by system or user. detect if there's an odex file of my app in data/app folder or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are ODEX files in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593527/what-are-odex-files-in-android)

Comment: I am developer android app.
I want to know what is java code should I embed to my android app to detect if its has been odexed by system or user.
detect if there's an odex file of my app in data/app folder or not.