# A method with no statements inside and ends with a semicolon

Tags: java, methods

So I came across a method like this in some source

```
public native void method();
```

There was code inside, but it was commented out,

```
/*MANUAL code code code */
```

The code looked a bit like C++.
So what does this mean? I know it does something because eventually it was called in the class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a declaration for a *native* method, indicated by the `native` modifier, as explained in the Java Language Specification, section [§8.4.3.4 `native` Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.4) .

You won't find its implementing code in Java, it's referring to code that's either in the C libraries that are part of the implementation of the JDK in use, or part of a native library bundled with the code you're studying. Refer to the [JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to understand how this gets called from a Java program.

Answer (score 2):

The native keyword in Java signifies the method is written in another language. See this exact question: [What is the native keyword in Java for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for)

Answer (score 1):

the keyword `native` states that this method's implementation comes from a native language like c/cpp etc via [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/)

A common example: a couple of methods in [java.lang.Object](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Object.java#Object) class are implemented in native language.

Answer (score 0):

The native keyword is applied to a method to indicate that the method is implemented in native code using [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html). It marks a method, that it will be implemented in other languages, not in Java in other word, native is implemented in platform-dependent code, typically written in another programming language.

You can find more example from [here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/jniex.htm).