# what is difference between Java Method And Native Method?

Tags: java, jvm

While studying Java , I stuck with concept of java Method and Native Method.Both have some Difference.I don't understand clearly what they meant?.
Please help me,Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Java method is generically a code block with a name that you can write using plain java.

```
public void method() {
    System.out.println("I'm a java method!");
}
```

A **native** method is a method that is linked to a native library. Native libraries are linked to a java program through [JNI (Java Native Interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA (Java Native Access)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) and a native method looks like this:

```
public native void method();
```

It's just a declaration, because the method implementation is done in the native library.

Answer (score 1):

By definition :

> Native methods are Java methods that start in a language other than Java.
>   Native methods can access system-specific functions and APIs that are not available directly in Java.

Whereas the Java methods are written specifically in Java as language.