# Why is there commented-out code in native method?

Tags: java, gwt

Recently, I've seen a lot of methods with the "native" keyword. It seems very common to have, **what seems like, commented out code**.

```
public native Something Foo(arg, arg) /*-{
    var foo = some.Method(arg);
    return foo;
}-*/;
```

I don't really understand **what the commented-out portion is or why it's commented out**. For a good while now *I've thought that this was just commented out code*. I'm starting to see it in more projects now (for instance, it's in the gwt source code).

Is the commented-out code significant in some way I don't understand? **I've read about the native keyword**, and I **understand what it means** and how it's used in a basic sense. **It's just confusing to see this "commented-out code" so often.**

Can someone explain the comments. Are they really comments? Are they significant?

[Update]
The question was about the commented out portion. I was starting to see it often enough I thought there was some significance that I was missing. Something like an annotation, for instance. I just wanted to be clear onwhy there were commented out sections of code littered all over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the native keyword in Java for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for)

Comment: It is just a comment which looks like the body of the ``native`` implemented (C/C++) code

Comment: @cr0ss It's not a duplicate. I'm not asking what the native keyword does. I understand that already (like I said in my post). I was wondering if there was significance to the code that seemed like it was commented out.

Comment: @loctrice For easier understanding, you can imaginarily replace ``native`` with ``abstract``

Comment: I updated my question. Perhaps now it will be clearer what I'm asking. I understand what native means. I wasn't sure if the comments, after seeing them so often, had some significance (something like an annotation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the gwt code is compiled in two distinct part : java for the server part and javascript for the client one.

The comment syntax in native methods

```
  /*-{ some javascript code }-*/
```

is a gwt specific way to write native javascript in the gwt code.

See [JSNI](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html)

Comment: That is fantastic, and makes sense. The projects I'm seeing it in are all gwt projects. I took the gwt tutorials to understand them, but I didn't look into making my own widgets until recently.

Answer (score 2):

`native` methods are implemented normally on c, and are platform dependant. You could see them as links to external libraries. The comment could tell you what the method is doing.