# Android native debug compiled with externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild

Tags: android, c++, debugging, android-ndk

I want to debug native code in Android Studio (version 2.2) in following examples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master-ndkbuild.

I have tried to edit app Run/Debug configuration and change debugger type to native or hybrid without success. Also tried to attach debuger selecting hybrid or native, but app doesn't stop on breakpoint in C++ code, when debugger is connected to process.

I have bigger project which is built simillary to linked examples. Currently rebuilding makefiles is not possible, therefore I want to run debugging with this kind or project setup. This kind of project setup means; using externalNativeBuild with ndk-build.

Does anyone know how to debug these examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get NDK debugging to work in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413593/how-to-get-ndk-debugging-to-work-in-android-studio)

Comment: @LBes He is talking about new feature in Android Studio 2.2 which is externalNativeBuild...

Comment: I've managed to debug native native code using cmake as externalNativeBuild and NDK r12+. Stil cant debug using ndk-build... looks like I have to rewrite all buildscripts to cmake.

Comment: @marioc64 any tips on native debug using cmake as externalNativeBuild?  I still can't hit any breakpoints in my native code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application's `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        initWith debug
        jniDebuggable true
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                cFlags "-DDEBUG=1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`cFlags` is optional, but useful. It's not described in [official Google docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html), i found it in [Android Gradle plugin DSL docs](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html)

Works on Android Studio 2.2.2+

Comment: Thanks for your reply, anyway my native build is rewritten to cmake.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly AS + gradle + ndk-build doesn't support debugging from IDE. The solution is to rewrite buildscripts to cmake.

Comment: This is not true. Debugging has nothing to do with how libraries are produced.

Comment: You're right, but the question is about debugging integration with Android Studio (IDE), not debugging at all.

Comment: Studio simply launches LLDB and connects it to a process. There is nothing about cmake or ndk-build that could enable or prevent that. As long as original library with debugging info is available it can be handled by LLDB.

Comment: It's possible, but gradle android plugin should set all the flags by default to correct state. Possibly @SBKarr answer is the solution but currently I am not checking this, because my build is switched to cmake.