# How do you debug android platform source code?

Tags: android, debugging, android-source

When you have issues with android source code, how do you dig into the code?
For example for this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127921/impossible-to-update-remove-specific-cookie-for-android-webview)
I saw from the debugger that the CookieManager is `AwCookieManager`.
So from [Google search](https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview/blob/master/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwCookieManager.java) I found that the setCookie is the following:

```
public void setCookie(final String url, final String value) {  
        nativeSetCookie(url, value);     
}
```

But I had trouble finding that native code to see what's going on.
I searched again in Google and found different version of this native and java and ended up with this file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/4bcd50196a7fe4c0c909ce6a7cfac6a808336611/Source/WebKit/android/jni/CookieManager.cpp

but I am not sure if this is the right file to look at and I suspect there is a smarter way for debugging these kind of things. I also wasn't sure how to find the called methods from that file.

So how do you do it?

Comment: The official guide has a [whole section](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) on debugging Android applications. It might be worth being more specific on what you wish to achieve. Have you tried using a debugger tool? Is it really of your interest to inspect the native library's source code?

Comment: @E_net4wisheshappyholidays: Yes it is of interest since I don't understand why the code does not work. I would like to inspect the actual logic. Debugger in Android Studio does not take into native code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get NDK debugging to work in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413593/how-to-get-ndk-debugging-to-work-in-android-studio)

Comment: you just have to run `make idegen && development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh` from the root directory of the sources to use Android Studio. dual debugger is way more convenient that using two independent debuggers.

Answer (score 0):

For java code debugging, use Java remote debug, [check this](http://ronubo.blogspot.com/2016/01/debugging-aosp-platform-code-with.html)

For C++ code debugging, use GDB remote debug, [check this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/gdb)