# I don't understand how to DetectionBasedTracker functions

Tags: java, android, opencv, sample

I don't understand the function of the native metods called in this sample.
Someone can explain me why we use native metods and how does it work?

```
package org.opencv.samples.facedetect;

import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;

public class DetectionBasedTracker
{
    public DetectionBasedTracker(String cascadeName, int minFaceSize) {
        mNativeObj = nativeCreateObject(cascadeName, minFaceSize);
    }

    public void start() {
        nativeStart(mNativeObj);
    }

    public void stop() {
        nativeStop(mNativeObj);
    }

    public void setMinFaceSize(int size) {
        nativeSetFaceSize(mNativeObj, size);
    }

    public void detect(Mat imageGray, MatOfRect faces) {
        nativeDetect(mNativeObj, imageGray.getNativeObjAddr(), faces.getNativeObjAddr());
    }

    public void release() {
        nativeDestroyObject(mNativeObj);
        mNativeObj = 0;
    }

    private long mNativeObj = 0;

    private static native long nativeCreateObject(String cascadeName, int minFaceSize);
    private static native void nativeDestroyObject(long thiz);
    private static native void nativeStart(long thiz);
    private static native void nativeStop(long thiz);
    private static native void nativeSetFaceSize(long thiz, int size);
    private static native void nativeDetect(long thiz, long inputImage, long faces);
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java not C++

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for

Comment: @Tunaki thank you for your answer!

Comment: someone know how this particulary metods works??

Comment: @Tunaki do you know what nativeStart and nativeStope do??