# What does JavaFX use under the hood to play sound?

Tags: javafx, javasound

I had some problems with playing sound using JavaFX on my Mac, so I decided to dig a little. I've found class called OSXMediaPlayer, with method that has the following signature:

```
private native void osxPlay() throws MediaException;
```

and - unfortunately - an empty body. Does that mean that Java call OSX command under the hood? Can I open a terminal and try it myself?

Comment: `native` means the method is not written in Java - the code will probably be written in C using macOS audio APIs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the native keyword in Java for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that Java call OSX command under the hood?

It does not call a *command line* program. It calls the native macOS audio [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) [CoreAudio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Audio) or [AVFoundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVFoundation).

> Can I open a terminal and try it myself?

No, because the terminal only lets you access *command line* programs, not APIs.