# What Is The Difference Between A Native App & A Hybrid App Development?

Tags: native, hybrid

Whenever one talks about Native vs Hybrid apps, the first thing that comes to mind is the basic conceptual difference between the two. So help me to know Basic diffrence for this.

Comment: One of the first hits on searching for "hybrid app": https://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the native keyword in Java for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for)

Answer (score 0):

**Native APP**
Native apps are developed for a particular platform. Like android apps are native apps. When it comes to user experience, they are the fastest and most reliable.

**Hybrid APP**
Hybrid apps are developed for both native and web applications. They can also use cross-compatible web technologies. Hybrid apps are typically easier and faster to develop than native apps.